# Installation blocked by bitlocker

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

Trying to install 20.04 from a flash drive into an HP ProDesk with a Toshiba SSD,  alongside Win 10.  All goes well until I get to a screen that tells me to disable the bitlocker manager.  So I go to the system in Control Panel, as instructed, and it tells me bitlocker is not active.  And that is where I am stuck.   How do I get past this?

Comment: Is the bitlocker simply deactivated or have you removed it?

Comment: Neither.  When I go to Control Panel/Bitlocker Drive Encryption, it reads "Windows (C) waiting for activation" and a shield "Turn on bitlocker"      But when I go to Disk Management, it reads ""healthy EFI  -  Windows (C) Bitlocker Encrypted - Healthy Recovery"   My C drive is a Toshiba SSD and my PC is a HP ProDesk 630.  I am using Win 10 1909 and I am told my PC "is not ready" for the Win 10 2020 update.

Comment: "Waiting for activation" meaning you haven't activated windows yet? Have you ever turned BitLocker on before? Is this what you see in control pannel? https://i.imgur.com/2Dx2BK7.png

Comment: I am using Win 10 1909.  Your link IS what I see when go to Control Panel.

Comment: Have you ever turned it on before and is your windows not activated?

Comment: I am using Win10, 1909.  The "activation" refers to whether or not bitlocker is activated.  Disk Management says it is;  Control Panel for bitlocker indicates it is not!  I see no way to deactivate it.  I think the Toshiba SSD had bitlocker applied to it at the factory, by Toshiba software, and can't be removed by Windows software.  In other words, If I want to use Ubuntu I will have to do it from a thumb drive.

Comment: Have you tried disable secure boot in Windows?

Comment: my solution is here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305270/bitlocker-is-blocking-ubuntu-20-04-installation-in-a-dual-boot-system-with-windo/1305282#1305282

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same scenario as I try to setup up the dual boot after having received a factory new dell laptop. Turned out for me that the "activation required" step simply is a UI stage as Windows wants me to savely store the recovery key on some media. After having done this and the "activation step" has been completed the device is shown to be encrypted without any processing. So the encryption was already in place, as the disk management and ubuntu both remark.

After activation the GUI shows the regular "device encrypted" screen and options so that the regular guides for decryption can be followed.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/disable-bitlocker?view=win10-ps

So I have done this in Powershell :

Disable-BitLocker

Remove-BitLockerKeyProtector

Unlock-BitLocker

One of this 3 commands worked but I do not know witch one ?! After that I have seen that in Disk Management the drive is without the word Bitlocker . Then back to Ubuntu installation and it worked perfect and I could install Ubuntu 20.04 in a dual boot with Win 10 64