# Installing Ubuntu -- problem with bitlocker

Tags: dual-boot

I would like to install a dual-boot of Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 on a Thinkpad X1 Extreme.

Ubuntu installer asks me to disable BitLocker under Windows. After doing so, the same message pops up again.

I also activated and deactivated BitLocker. `manage-bde -status` returns that "C:" is fully decrypted (no other partition is shown).

But Ubuntu installation still complains about BitLocker. Any ideas?

Related to: [Installation blocked by bitlocker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238641/installation-blocked-by-bitlocker/1251797?noredirect=1#comment2113343_1251797)

Comment: did you disable secure boot ?

Comment: That solved it. Thanks!