# BitLocker is blocking Ubuntu 20.04 installation in a dual boot system with Windows 10 64

Tags: dual-boot

I have Windows 10 64 as primary OS , now I  am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04, latest version on the site  and to have dual boot .
When I am trying to do that I have this error from Ubuntu installation
[image]

[image: bitlocker encryption]

bitlocker encryption is saying that it is not encrypted

Disk managment is saying that it is encrypted this partition

in powershell is saying that it is not encrypted .
[image]

I have disable secure boot from bios too , does not work .
So 2 are saying that it is and 2 are saying that it is not .

How I solved this please ? thank you

[image]

Comment: Looks more a Windows problem than an Ubuntu one. Maybe try asking on SuperUser instead of here...

Comment: it is in between them ,  like on Windows but it is  in Ubuntu too , is affecting both , thank you for your answer , I have already solved

Answer (score 8):

On Windows 10 Home (Where Bit Locker Encryption does not show)
I was just able to stop encryption.

Open **Start>>Settings**, then type "bitlocker" on search bar (In Setting not Control Panel)

Now you will find **"Change Device Encryption Settings"** and when you open that tab, you will find **turn off** option, or go to bitlocker settings.

Step 2. After that go to command Prompt(or PowerShell) by Admin

```
Disable-Bitlocker -MountPoint "C:"
```

In my case it was C drive

```
manage-bde -off "C:"
RESTART
```

System will initialize BIOS settings and Flash Setting on restart.

---

Part 2. Patience: There is more.
It will start Decrypting. You can check Encryption % using below cmd

```
Disable-Bitlocker -MountPoint "C:"
```

You may check DiskManagement in Computer Management for the same.

Answer (score 0):

> Did that : I faced the same scenario as I try to setup up the dual
> boot after having received a factory new dell laptop. Turned out for
> me that the "activation required" step simply is a UI stage as Windows
> wants me to savely store the recovery key on some media. After having
> done this and the "activation step" has been completed the device is
> shown to be encrypted without any processing. So the encryption was
> already in place, as the disk management and ubuntu both remark.
>
> After activation the GUI shows the regular "device encrypted" screen
> and options so that the regular guides for decryption can be followed.

s10z

Did that and I have noticed that he is right and it is locked the drive C .
But still did not work just with that .

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/disable-bitlocker?view=win10-ps

So I have done this in Powershell :

1. Disable-BitLocker
2. Remove-BitLockerKeyProtector
3. Unlock-BitLocker

One of this commands worked but I do not know witch one ?!
After that I have seen that in Disk Management the drive is without the word Bitlocker .
Then back to Ubuntu installation and it worked  perfect and I could install Ubuntu 20.04 in a dual boot with Win 10 64

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. While I turned Bitlocker off on C: - the Recovery partition was also Bitlocker encrypted and I had to turn off the encryption for that partition too. For this you will need to assign a drive letter to the recovery partition and then it will show up in the Bitlocker menu (there I enabled and disabled the encryption). After that Ubuntu installed as expected.